# Why do some sites use jquery with a $j instead of just a $?

Tags: jquery

I generally use this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
}
```

I was just on a site that heavily uses jquery and they call it using

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
}
```

On this site they start almost everything out with a j...

```
function PostComment(form) {
  form = $j(form);
  $j('#CommentSubmitButton').hide();
  $j('#CommentInProgress').show();
  $j.post('/utils/ajaxhandler.aspx', form.serialize(), function(data) {
    $j('#CommentInProgress').hide();
    $j('#CommentSubmitButton').show();
  });
}
```

Is this just another way of doing it or is this dependent on a differnt version of jquery or other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define, how you want to call the jquery functionality.
Maybe this site uses another library, which reserves the $, and for that reason used the alias $j.

Comment: good to know, can you just "do it" or do you need to define it/set it somewhere else?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function

Answer (score 8):

This is to avoid colision with other libraries with:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

For instance some libraries like prototype also use the $ sign, and if you end up using both it will most likely break. If you developed your jquery functions using $j it won't.

Comment: In the case of this site, they probably say $j = jQuery.noConflict(); - then $j is available as the $ from jQuery, and the previous meaning of $ (if any) is overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a method to avoid naming conflicts. Many JavaScript libraries (jQuery happens to be one of them) uses $ as a shortcut. For more information, see [jQuery.noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict)

Answer (score 2):

Its definitely to avoid collision with other libraries.  The most notorious of which would be prototype and scriptaculous.